# Is MS SQL Server 2014 the best choice for migration of an ADP project from Access 2010 to php?

Tags: php, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2014, adp

I have inherited an old MS Access 2010 ".ADP" project that is currently connecting to MS SQL 2005 server. The Access project is mainly a bunch of reports pulled from SQL 2005 Stored Procedures.   My plan is migrate to Amazon EC2 and I wondering if I can Jump all the way to MS SQL 2014 or and still connect to the new server with my ".ADP" app while I work on the migration to PHP.

Will Access 2010 ".ADP" work with SQL Server 2014**?

Comment: Well I disagree... My question is "will it work" and it deserves an answer.  I will reword the question.

Comment: Please take the question off hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that ...

1. Microsoft has deprecated Access ADP projects to the point where Access 2013 will not work with them **at all**,
2. you are in the process of porting the ADP project to another platform, and
3. it is unlikely that SQL Server 2014 would offer any significant advantages over an earlier version of SQL Server for the old ADP project

... I would suggest that you keep your setup as close as possible to the older (known working) configuration.

My gut says yes, it is probably "relatively safe" to expect that SQL Server 2014 would not horribly break something built for an earlier version of SQL Server, but why take the risk of jumping ahead three versions (2008 -> 2008 R2 -> 2012 -> 2014) for an ADP project that is "on its way out" anyway?

Comment: Gord, thanks for this answer.  I think your correct.  I hope someone has actually run one of these combo and can report back.